# Need to get last 60 days of Files from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working in ado.net. I have a table where I saved my files. When the files are saved I also save date and time with SQL function `GETDATE()`. What I need is to hit a query in database to fetch last 60 days data from current date. Is there any function or any query for this scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming there is a column called something like `DateSaved` that stores the date when the record was saved:

```
Select * from YourFiles where DateSaved > DateAdd(d, -60, GetDate())
```

The `d` means we are adding units of 'Day', the -60 means we are adding negative 60 of them, and all together it means we are adding negative 60 days to the current date.

Comment: i use this what getting all data from table not last 60 .in current i testing and using last 7 days

Comment: Select * from BLK_CSV_FILE where IS_UPLOADED_DATE > DateAdd(dd, -7, GetDate())

Comment: What values do you have in the IS_UPLOADED_DATE column? "Select IS_UPLOADED_DATE, Count(*) from BLK_CSV_FILE group by IS_UP_LOADED_DATE Order by 1 asc"  ??

Comment: 2015-06-04 11:35:38.283   this type of value saved in that col.this data i get from getdate function i used this when i insert data in my table

Comment: thanks a lot i got my error and then this quarry works for my like a magic thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Name  WHERE DATEDIFF(D,GETDATE(),Date_Column)<-60
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM BLK_CSV_FILE  WHERE DATEDIFF(D,GETDATE(),IS_UPLOADED_DATE)<-7
this one is not getting even a single data

Comment: 2015-06-04 11:35:38.283
this type of data saved in my is_uploaded_date filed

Comment: that value is today, if is_uploaded_date hold the value of 2015-05-20 then the query will execute